# Moving wordpress site to subpage of another site

Tags: export

So I'm in a scenario where our company has site.com and we acquired an organization who now operates under our name.

I would like to move their entire site as a subpage of our site, so site.com/acquiredpages and that subpage is their index pages and it goes from there.

The acquired companies website is built in wordpress, what are the steps to be done to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want the `acquiredpages` directory to still be a WordPress installation, or do you only require the HTML content + images and other assets from the acquired company's site?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

1. Log into "other organization"
2. install [All In One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)
3. make a copy of your site
4. download said copy
5. In `site.com` Create a directory called `acquiredpages`
6. install a blank copy of Wordpress
7. log into your blank wordpress
8. install [All In One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)
9. run the migration with the file from step 4.

This should work for most wordpress sites and I've used it to migrate dozens of client sites. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

1) Download all the files by ftp and upload it to the new location or new folder (acquiredpages). 
2) Download database and host it on your server, and update the credentials in wp-config. 
3) Update value of siteurl and home in wp_options table 
4) edit the .htaccess file and modify

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /acquiredpages/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /acquiredpages/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

add 'acquiredpages' (folder name) wherever I have mentioned.

4) If required run search and replace in files and database.

Comment: I would not recommend downloading their entire wp-install, however, just to avoid the possibility of infected core, theme, or plugin files. Install a fresh copy of WordPress core, theme, and plugins, and then `wget` their `uploads` folder. This way you will not inherit any problems if they had a less than careful IT guy.

Comment: If they can miss out the themes and plugins, then everything can be messed up if there are customizations.

Comment: Ah, yes. But you shouldn't edit WordPress core or theme files. They should use a child theme for that, and if they are using one, again, they should upload a fresh copy of that, if they have it.